# Scraping urls asynchronous including exception handling

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, asynchronous

I'm trying to understand how to work with `aiohttp` and `asyncio`. The code below retrieves all websites in `urls` and prints out the "size" of each response.

- Is the error handling within the fetch method correct?
- Is it possible to remove the result of a specific url from `results` in case of an exception - making `return (url, '')` unnecessary?
- Is there a better way than `ssl=False` to deal with a potential `ssl.SSLCertVerificationError`?
- Any additional advice on how i can improve my code quality is highly appreciated

```
import asyncio
import aiohttp


async def fetch(session, url):
    try:
        async with session.get(url, ssl=False) as response:
            return url, await response.text()
    except aiohttp.client_exceptions.ClientConnectorError as e:
        print(e)
        return (url, '')


async def main():
    tasks = []
    urls = [
        'http://www.python.org',
        'http://www.jython.org',
        'http://www.pypy.org'
    ]
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        while urls:
            tasks.append(fetch(session, urls.pop()))

        results = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
        [print(f'{url}: {len(result)}') for url, result in results]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
    loop.close()
```

**Update**

- Is there a way how i can add tasks to the list from within the "loop"? e.g. add new urls while scraping a website and finding new subdomains to scrape.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> tasks = []
> while urls:
>     tasks.append(fetch(session, urls.pop()))
> ```

can be largely simplified to

```
tasks = [fetch(session, url) for url in urls]
```

---

> Is it possible to remove the result of a specific url from `results` in case of an exception - making `return (url, '')` unnecessary?

Yes, somewhat. [`asyncio.gather`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.gather) accept a `return_exceptions` parameters. Set it to `True` to avoid a single exception failing the `gather` call. You must filter them out afterwards anyway:

```
import asyncio
import aiohttp


async def fetch(session, url):
    async with session.get(url, ssl=False) as response:
        return await response.text()


async def main():
    urls = [
        'http://www.python.org',
        'http://www.jython.org',
        'http://www.pypy.org'
    ]
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        tasks = [fetch(session, url) for url in urls]
        results = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

    for url, result in zip(urls, results):
        if not isinstance(result, Exception):
            print(f'{url}: {len(result)}')
        else:
            print(f'{url} FAILED')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
    loop.close()
```

Comment: Not sure if your code example is meant to catch exceptions or if you just wanted to point out how to deal with exceptions in the `results` list. I only manage to have a working code if i put `try... except` within the `fetch` method. If put `return e` in `except` your code works.